# React JS SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, internet-explorer, post

I am using React 15.x version in my application and weirdly getting the following error on IE11:

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3.

This happens when I make a `POST` request to my web server. There is no fixed pattern when this happens but it happens intermittently. And it is not limited to 1 particular web service. happens randomly for one of the post requests. Neither I am sending huge data to server nor I have any timeout related loop in my app. Any idea why this happens?

There are related questions to this one but none seems to suggest a fix.

Comment: There are indeed quite a few related questions, some of which have answers which point to what appears to be a sensible possible fix: http://jonnyreeves.co.uk/2013/making-xhr-request-to-https-domains-with-winjs/ (I know this mentions WinJS, but the post is about XHR requests in general).

Comment: Yes, I read those. As he mentions: This error appears to be caused by a security certificate issue. How do we fix this security certificate issue? I can't make a GET request before a POST request. Its not legitimate.